# Is there a way to create specific values to display within the results of a saved search within NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, erp, saved-searches

I want to be able to display specific values within the results of my saved search if conditions are met.

[I want to combine, API, Email, and FeedStation into a field that is displayed as "Automated" within the saved search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU3A7.png)

[I want to change none and have it say "Drop Ship"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhOcD.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be using a `CASE` statement.  Replace the field in your Results tab with a Formula (Numeric) from the field selection.  In the Formula cell enter

```
CASE WHEN {field} IN ('API', 'Email', 'FeedStation') THEN 'Automated' ELSE {field} END
```

Similarly for the second example:

```
CASE WHEN {field} = '-None-' THEN 'Drop Ship' ELSE {field} END
```

In either case replace `{field}` with the internal id of the field in question, between braces.